# Can I use Puma threads on Heroku on a Rails App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, heroku, thread-safety, puma

Apparently Unicorn has been deprecated on Heroku, so we are going to try Puma. Is it possible to run multiple threads for a Rails app?

I read about concurrency in Rails, and it doesn't seem that it is possible to guarantee that all code and gems are thread safe.

So, is it possible to run Rails apps on Heroku using Puma threads?

Rails 4.1.7.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. With Rails 4.1.7 and Puma in their default configuration, Puma will use between 0-16 threads. This is a fine place to start.

Heroku has a guide for using Puma: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server